# Pytest parameterized fixtures with other parameterized arguments

Tags: python, pytest

I have a parameterized fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def config(val1, val2):
    yield {
    "key1": val1,
    "key2": val2
    }
```

and a test like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "val1, val2, some_other_arg", [(1, 2, "alpha")]
)
def test_config(config, some_other_arg):
    os.environ["test-stage"] = some_other_arg
    ...
```

when I try this, I get an error `function uses no argument 'some_other_arg'` because its trying to match `some_other_arg` with fixture args and finding a mismatch.

How can I send other parametrized values along with a parameterized fixture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing/mixing the fixture and parameterization.

The following all-parameter approach should work:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "val1, val2, some_other_arg", [(1, 2, "alpha")]
)
def test_config(val1, val2, some_other_arg):
    os.environ["test-stage"] = some_other_arg
    ...
```

To mix fixtures and parameters, the parameters must come first:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "some_other_arg", [("alpha")]
)
def test_config(some_other_arg, config):
    os.environ["test-stage"] = some_other_arg
    assert config['key1'] == ...
    ...
```

In your example code, you had sort of destructured the `config` fixture. That unfortunately can't be done.